# How to remove the next button in the basic activity in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I selected the basic activity for my new project. 
T
here is a next button which already placed over there. and I am not able to delete or remove the button. How can I remove the next button?
I have attached the screenshot. Also, I don't want the fragment sections.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

From toolbar section navigate to code or split tab, check the button tag widget in  XML and remove it, you won't see any button.

If you want to remove fragment, from left project navigation menu, open android packages and on src java files select class or file you want to remove and then press delete.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove this line in your XML:

`<include layout="@layout/content_action_bar_activiy" />`

and then it will be removed from your Activity.